# Role Reactions Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been trying to code a discord bot in discord.js with a command that allows user to react to the message and receive a role. This is my current code. I am unsure how to make it where when a user's added a reaction it gives a role and when the reaction for a user has removed the role it took away.

```
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const colors = require("../colors");
const botconfig = require("../botconfig");



exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

   await message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});

  const role1 = message.guild.roles.get('688477558982836344'); // Replace with Updates ID
  const role2 = message.guild.roles.get('688477690344374283'); // Replace with Events ID
  const role3 = message.guild.roles.get('688477467840872452'); // Replace with QOTD ID
  const role4 = message.guild.roles.get('688477868078137369'); // Replace with Polls ID
  const role5 = message.guild.roles.get('687498488295981069'); // Replace with Social Media ID

  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('Pinged Roles')
        .setDescription(`

        Tip: *Double React to remove a role*

        ❤️ ${role1.toString()}
         ${role2.toString()}
         ${role3.toString()}
         ${role4.toString()}
         ${role5.toString()}

        `)
        .setColor(colors.purple)
        .setFooter('mc.advancius.net')

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {

    await msg.react('❤️');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');
    await msg.react('');


    }); 

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "roles"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems like you are using Discord.js v11, but I'll include code for v12 as well because that's the latest version.

### v11

You'll need to use the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) and [`messageReactionRemove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove) events of `Client` as [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/ReactionCollector) has no `remove` event.

```js
// I added this object because I prefer having this than having lots of repeated code
// you can still do this the way you were doing before
const roles = {
  '❤️': '688477558982836344',
  '': '688477690344374283',
  '': '688477467840872452',
  '': '688477868078137369',
  '': '687498488295981069'
}

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  await message.delete()

  const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pinged Roles')
    .setDescription(`
      Tip: *Double React to remove a role*

      ${Object.entries(roles)
        .map(([emoji, id]) => `${emoji} ${message.guild.roles.get(id).toString()}`)
        .join('\n')}
    `)
    .setColor(colors.purple)
    .setFooter('mc.advancius.net')

  message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
    // react with every emoji
    for (const emoji of Object.keys(roles)) await msg.react(emoji)

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      // if the message that the user reacted to is the same as the message with
      // the reactions, add the role
      if (message.id === msg.id) message.guild.members.get(user.id).addRole(roles[emoji.name])
    })

    client.on('messageReactionRemove', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      // same as above but remove the role
      if (message.id === msg.id) message.guild.members.get(user.id).removeRole(roles[emoji.name])
    })
  })
}
```

### v12/v13

You can use [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) as [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/ReactionCollector) has a [`remove`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-remove) event, which fires when a reaction is removed.

```js
// I added this object because I prefer having this than having lots of repeated code
// you can still do this the way you were doing before
const roles = {
  '❤️': '688477558982836344',
  '': '688477690344374283',
  '': '688477467840872452',
  '': '688477868078137369',
  '': '687498488295981069'
}

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  await message.delete()

  // because RoleManager.fetch is async
  const rolesArray = await Promise.all(Object.entries(roles)
    .map(async ([emoji, id]) => `${emoji} ${(await message.guild.roles.fetch(id)).toString()}`)
  )
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Pinged Roles')
    .setDescription(`
      Tip: *Double React to remove a role*

      ${rolesArray.join('\n')}
    `)
    .setColor(colors.purple)
    .setFooter('mc.advancius.net')

  // for v12:
  // message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
  message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]}).then(async msg => {
    const emojis = Object.keys(roles)
    for (const emoji of emojis) await msg.react(emoji)

    // only collect reactions that are the role emojis
    // for v12:
    // const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(({emoji}) => emojis.includes(emoji.name))
    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector({
      filter: ({emoji}) => emojis.includes(emoji.name)
    })

    collector.on('collect', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(member => {
        member.roles.add(roles[emoji.name])
      })
    })

    collector.on('remove', ({emoji, message}, user) => {
      message.guild.members.fetch(user).then(member => {
        member.roles.remove(roles[emoji.name])
      })
    })
  })
}
```